# Javascript get array information with variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have an Array and want to get the infos on a specify day:

```
var today = new Date();
var Days = ['Sonntag','Montag',"Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag","Freitag","Montag"];
var Day = Days[today.getDay()];

alert(Stundenplan.Day[5].Fach);
```

When I replace the "Day" in the alert with (for example) "Montag" it's work perfekt. But with the variable its dont work.

There is a part of my array:

```
var Stundenplan = {
    Montag: [ {
       Fach: "0",
       Einpacken: "0"
     },
         {
       Fach: "1",
       Einpacken: "1"
     },
         {
       Fach: "2",
       Einpacken: "2"
     },
          {
       Fach: "3",
       Einpacken: "3"
     },
          {
       Fach: "4",
       Einpacken: "x"
     },
          {
       Fach: "xx5",
       Einpacken: "xx"
     },
          {
       Fach: "pause",
       Einpacken: "pause"
     },
         {
       Fach: "Sport",
       Einpacken: "Sporttasche"
     },
          {
       Fach: "Sport",
       Einpacken: "Sporttasche"
    }
   ],
            [.......]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `console.log(today.getDay())`. What does it tell you?

Comment: @rplantiko has already answered, but it seems you're missing `'Samstag'`

Comment: I know, I have changed this to test Monday on a Saturday :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the dynamic access to a hash element (i.e. the key is stored in the variable `Day`). Instead of the dot operator, you can access a hash element by specifying its key in square brackets, like so:

```
alert(Stundenplan[Day][5].Fach);
```